# Maximum number of polygons

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

What is the number of polygons than can be formed from 
(i) 10 concurrent lines 
(ii) 10 pair wise non parallel lines intersecting one another

Polygons have finite areas .

Comment: Hint: $N_{(i)} + N_{(ii)}$  is the $10^{th}$ entry of [Lazy's caterer's sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_caterer's_sequence).

Comment: If I use this - 10c3 + 10c4 + 10c5 +....+ 10c10 , why would the answer that I get be wrong ?

Comment: Hmm.. when you say polygon, do you allow polygons that get cut by other lines. If you allow that, the problem will be significantly harder...

Comment: What would be the ans if I allow that ?

Comment: If that is indeed the case,  then I don't know the answer.

Comment: I am not English speaker and I can't understand the difference between i) and ii). Anyway the maximum number of finite polygons with $n$  lines ($n\geq 3$) is the triangular number $T_{n-2}=\dfrac{(n-2)(n-1)}{2}$

Comment: In case 1 [ that is (i) ] all the lines are meeting at a single point but this is not necessary in case 2 [ that is (ii) ]. In case 2 , the lines can intersect each other at distinct points.